# Why converting date from nvarchar(max) to date throws error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a date in this format

```
21-02-2018
```

and using `nvarchar(MAX)`

I am trying to convert to date using

```
  select (Convert(Date, , 106)) from Certificates

  select (Convert(Date, IssueDate))
```

but it fails to convert.

Comment: What's the error message? and why you're storing dates as strings in the first place

Comment: Don't store dates as strings in the first place. That's a localized date format anyway. You can use `PARSE` or `TRY_PARSE` with the correct culture specifier to parse it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `try_convert()`.  However, I think you want format 105 (dd-mm-yyyy), not 106 (dd mon yyyy):

```
select try_convert(date, issuedate, 105)
```

This will return `NULL` instead of failing, when the format does not match.  You can find these values:

```
select issuedate
from certificates
where try_convert(date, issuedate, 105) is null and
      issuedate is not null;
```

Comment: This returns NULL

Comment: @RedDevil  select try_convert(date,'21-02-2018', 105) returns a valid date.  any NULL is because the conversion failed due to some other reason

Comment: @RedDevil I can verify it returns `2018-02-21`. What did you try?

Comment: select try_convert(date, '2019-10-14', 105)

Comment: @RedDevil that's *not* what the OP posted at all. You should have used `14-10-2019`

Comment: @Gordon explain it nicely

Answer (score 0):

This is usually down to the format that the server is expecting the date to come in.  I believe that it defaults to Month-Day-Year (American) rather than Day-Month-Year (British)

Try putting `SET DATEFORMAT DMY` at the start of your code to hint that the first part of the string is Day not month.